# Regex: select first words of lines starting with specified character

Tags: php, regex

I'm looking for regex pattern  like this:

```
<html>
<body>
@info
<input>.........</input>
@ok_test somthin here
</body>
</html>
```

I want to get  all strings which begin with '@'.
I tried `explode` in php but can't get rid of the rest string after space.
I tried my regex like this :

```
\b@[a-zA-Z0-9]*
```

But still can't.
Could someone help me?
Thanks.

Comment: `\b` before `@` requires a word char before it.  You must have tried with `\B` instead. And `[a-zA-Z0-9]*` is not matching `_`, you should have use `\w+`.

Comment: i tried this with `/([ ]*@([a-zA-Z0-9_])+)/g` and it worked. But when i used `preg_match`, php pop up error about `/g`.

Comment: Sure, because you cannot use `/g` in PHP `preg_` functions. I think you just want to get all matches, use `preg_match_all` - `preg_match_all('~\B@\w+~', $input, $matches);` -> `print_r($matches[0]);`

Comment: it works. thanks a lot.

Comment: but why it return extra `array[1]`? I checked my .html and  don't see any thing have like : `@a @l` or else

Comment: See my answer, `preg_match_all` will just return an array of arrays. You need to access `[0]` to get the *matches* only.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
/(^\@)[^\s]+/gm
```

It selects:

- every line starting with **@**
- all the following characters up to whitespace **[^\s]+**

Answer (score 0):

The `\b` [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) before `@` requires a word char (a letter, or digit, or a `_`) before it. You must have tried with `\B` instead, a non-word boundary. The `[a-zA-Z0-9]*` is not matching `_`, you should have use `\w+`, one or more letters/digits/underscores.

To get multiple matches, you need to use [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php), not [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) with a regex having `/g` modifier (that PHP regex does not support).

Use

```
$input = "@info and more here\nText here: @ok_test somthin here";
preg_match_all('~\B@\w+~', $input, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

See [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/Vha3z9) yielding

```
Array
(
    [0] => @info
    [1] => @ok_test
)
```